# Can't select element from page [Selenium[

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have tried to scrap info from that site - specifically, from a table. Every time I occur, info that elements doesn't exist.

> https://polygonscan.com/token/0x64a795562b02830ea4e43992e761c96d208fc58d

I try to add `time.slep(5)` to my code or scrolling down function to load all element - ineffective.

Do you have any advice for me?

**EDIT**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


# Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

# Set drive
chrome_driver_path = r"C:\Users\kacpe\OneDrive\Pulpit\Python\Projekty\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://polygonscan.com/token/0x64a795562b02830ea4e43992e761c96d208fc58d")


try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr[0]")))
    print(element)
except TimeoutException as e:
    print(e)
```

I added code in regard to your request. So my main goal is to scrap content from the table at this site. I add Explicit Waits to my code and still I can't select anything from that table - it's looking like the script doesn't see anything from that area.

Answer (score 0):

One way to try solve it, its using the Xpath of the element or the relative position of the same, to make Selenium, get allways the same "line" of position to return the "value" of the information that you are searching.

Ex1:find_element(:xpath,"//*[@id="wmd-input"]")#in that case it's the input of this check box.

If it doesnt work, try this one.

Ex2: **browser.implicitly_wait(30)** #makes a timer to load all the informations from the web to your machine.

Comment: First: Please post a [Minimum Reproducible Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to look into the issue effectively.

Second: Scraping could be done two ways, one with bs4 and another with Selenium (or both too), but you didn't state what you used. Going by the tag, selenium, I would say you can use `WebdriverWait` and  `visibility_of_element_located`. This would help you to wait for a set timeout, while checking for the visibility of the target element

Comment: Though `implicitly_wait` works, it is not advisable/preferrable when scaling up the code. `Implicitly_wait` once set must be closed, otherwise it would apply itself to the entire code, which would hamper the performance overall. Hence, it is explicit waits such as `WebdriverWait` that should be preferred, whose function would terminate when its job is done.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have edited my original post. Your advice doesn't work